# Creating a Serializable mock with Mockito error

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, serializable

I'm trying to create a mock object with Mockito that can be serialized. The object is an interface implementation. When this method is called, I receive an object that I want to pass to another object, hence using the doAnswer(...)-method.
This is my code.

```
InterfaceClass obj = mock(InterfaceClass.class, withSettings().serializable());
    doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            //Here I do something with the arguments
        }
    }).when(obj).someMethod(
            any(someObject.class));

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    try {
      out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
      out.writeObject(obj);
      byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    } finally {
      out.close();
      bos.close();
    }
```

As far as I can tell this should be correct (I'm fairly new to Mockito).
But when Serializing my object I get this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.trust1t.ocs.signcore.test.InvalidInputTestCase$1
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:329)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.writeObject(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:644)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:950)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1482)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:329)
at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:943)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:950)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1482)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1413)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:329)
at com.trust1t.ocs.signcore.test.InvalidInputTestCase.certificateValidationTest(InvalidInputTestCase.java:117)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The invalidInputTestCase class is the class containing the test where I'm using this code. It looks as if the mock object references this TestCase somewhere (can't find it though). 
Am I not correctly implementing this or better ideas to mock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to serialize a mock everything needs to be serializable, including the `Answer`.

And actually that's what the JDK is telling you :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.trust1t.ocs.signcore.test.InvalidInputTestCase$1
```

where `InvalidInputTestCase$1` is the name of the anonymous `Answer`.
To make it serializable you have to create a class implementing `Answer` and `Serializable`.

Also note that serialization across classloaders (JVM) is not yet released, at the moment you can only serialize and deserialize a mock in the same classloader.